# Android talkback announce "in list of X item" at the ending of listview

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

In some devices (nexus) when we tap on the first item in listview it will talkback as list item + " in list of X item". How can we remove the text " in list of X item"?

Please share your thought

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to control effectively how talkback behaves is to add content description on you views which should be described to the user:

**Java**

```
view.setContentDescription("Your text here");
```

**XML**

```
android:contentDescription="Your text here"
```

and views that have no meaning to someone using talkback set :

**JAVA**

```
view.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
```

**XML**

```
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

There are several options:
auto
noHideDescendants
yes
no

Please note that you can control view groups that way also.
Play with it a little.

Comment: android:importantForAccessibility="no" really works well for recyclerview to avoid announcing item count at the end.

Comment: android:importantForAccessibility="no" will indeed change the accessibility announcement but it will also disable other accessibility features for the RecyclerView such as swipe navigation, etc...

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution where you set weather the (RecyclerView or ListView) should be important for Accessibility directly.

If you set it to individual views items in the list, Talkback will still announce "x items" the first time that list gets created.

*In Kotlin:* "dataBinding.customRecyclerView.importantForAccessibility = *View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO*

Comment: True, the first time it still says In List / Out of List, but for rest of the items it does not say anything.
Now with RecyclerView 1.2 also it will be the same behaviour without setting importantForAccessibility